# How to retrieve attention weight alignment for tokens using transformer (BERT) model?

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, text-classification, transformer-model

I am working on text classification with transformer models (PyTorch, Huggingface, running on GPU).

I have already my model and my training loop and it works fine but to better understand wrong predictions of the model, I want to "dig a little deeper" and look at the attention weights the model gave the tokens of the misclassified predictions (for evaluation during training and later for predictions on the test set).

I tried already so many things and I already found a way the model outputs attention weights (will attach an example), BUT a) it outputs too many attention weights for each misclassified example (can it be because it gives the weights for several layers?) and b) the attention weights are not connected to the tokens. I want it in a more interpretable way, like coloring the tokens in a darker color the more weight is on that token.

This is my code so far (irrelevant snippets left out):

```
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(checkpoint,
                                                      num_labels=len(label_dict),
                                                      output_attentions=True,
                                                      output_hidden_states=True)
```

```
def get_wrong_predictions(predictions, true_vals):
    wrong_predictions = []
    for i in range(len(true_vals)):
        if np.argmax(predictions[i]) != true_vals[i]:
            wrong_predictions.append((true_vals[i], np.argmax(predictions[i])))
    return wrong_predictions
```

```
seed_val = 17
random.seed(seed_val)
np.random.seed(seed_val)
torch.manual_seed(seed_val)
torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed_val)

def evaluate(dataloader_val):

    model.eval()
    
    loss_val_total = 0
    predictions, true_vals = [], []
    attentions = []
    
    for batch in dataloader_val:
        
        batch = tuple(b.to(device) for b in batch)
        
        inputs = {'input_ids':      batch[0],
                  'attention_mask': batch[1],
                  'labels':         batch[2],
                 }

        with torch.no_grad():        
            outputs = model(**inputs)
            
        loss = outputs[0]
        logits = outputs[1]
        attention_scores = outputs.attentions[-1].detach().cpu().numpy() # extract the attention scores from the last layer
        loss_val_total += loss.item()

        logits = logits.detach().cpu().numpy()
        label_ids = inputs['labels'].cpu().numpy()
        predictions.append(logits)
        true_vals.append(label_ids)
        attentions.append(attention_scores)
    
    loss_val_avg = loss_val_total/len(dataloader_val) 
    
    predictions = np.concatenate(predictions, axis=0)
    true_vals = np.concatenate(true_vals, axis=0)
    attentions = np.concatenate(attentions, axis=0)
    
    preds = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
    misclassified = np.where(preds != true_vals)[0]

    texts = df["description"].tolist()
    
    global misclassified_examples
    misclassified_examples = []
    #misclassified = []

    for idx in misclassified[:min(len(attention_scores), len(misclassified))]:
        text = texts[idx]
        true_label = true_vals[idx]
        pred_label = preds[idx]
        attention_weights = attentions[idx] # get the attention weights for the misclassified examples
        misclassified_examples.append({
            'text': text,
            'true_label': true_label,
            'pred_label': pred_label,
            'attention_weights' : attention_weights
        })
            
    return loss_val_avg, predictions, true_vals

    
train_losses = [] #to plot later
val_losses = []
overall_accuracy = []
    
for epoch in tqdm(range(1, epochs+1)):
    
    model.train()
    
    loss_train_total = 0

    progress_bar = tqdm(dataloader_train, desc='Epoch {:1d}'.format(epoch), leave=False, disable=False)
    for batch in progress_bar:

        model.zero_grad()
        
        batch = tuple(b.to(device) for b in batch)
        
        inputs = {'input_ids':      batch[0],
                  'attention_mask': batch[1],
                  'labels':         batch[2],
                 }       

        outputs = model(**inputs)
        
        loss = outputs[0]
        loss_train_total += loss.item()
        loss.backward()

        torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 1.0)

        optimizer.step()
        scheduler.step()
        
        progress_bar.set_postfix({'training_loss': '{:.3f}'.format(loss.item()/len(batch))})
    
    loss_train_avg = loss_train_total/len(dataloader_train) #to plot later
    train_losses.append(loss_train_avg) # to plot later

    
        
    tqdm.write(f'\nEpoch {epoch}')
    
    loss_train_avg = loss_train_total/len(dataloader_train)            
    tqdm.write(f'Training loss: {loss_train_avg}')
    
    val_loss, predictions, true_vals = evaluate(dataloader_validation)
    val_f1 = f1_score_func(predictions, true_vals)
    tqdm.write(f'Validation loss: {val_loss}')
    tqdm.write(f'F1 Score (Weighted): {val_f1}')
    
    val_overallaccuracy = overallaccuracy(true_vals, predictions)
    tqdm.write(f'Overall Accuracy: {val_overallaccuracy}')
    
    val_mcc = mcc_score_func(true_vals, predictions)
    tqdm.write(f'MCC: {val_mcc}')
    
    val_acc = accuracy_per_class(predictions, true_vals)
    tqdm.write(f'Accuracy per class: {val_acc}')
    
    val_losses.append(val_loss)
    overall_accuracy.append(val_overallaccuracy)
```

The image shows exemplarily what kind of output I get, but that is "too much" attention as I expected one number for one token and then of course some way to relate that number of attention weight back to that token.

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTc6A.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICmvp.png)

How  could I adjust my code to include attention weight alignment for the tokens?

Answer (score -1):

From the official HuggingFace [page](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/output#transformers.modeling_outputs.BaseModelOutput.attentions), the attention parameters return a tuple containing each layer's attention. Each elements in the tuple are shaped as (batch_size, num_heads, sequence_length, sequence_length).

- batch_size: For each sentence, you will get different results as expected
- num_heads: The attention process is applied multiple times inside each layer (multiple attention mechanism). For example, in the Bert, there are 12 layers, and in each layer, there are 12 heads. This means that you have a total of 144 attention heads.
- sequence_length: The attention mechanism can be defined as a weighted average of the inputs. You have a shape of (sequence_length X emb_size) matrix, end the after the attention this shape will be the same. Therefore your attention scores have the shape of (sequence_length X sequence_length). How are they calculated? Each element of the matrix is calculated as the dot product of the corresponding inputs basically: Att[I,j] = dot(X_i, X_j) (I omitted weights for easing to reading).